# control panel for images slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making an image slider but now I want to add a control bar at the bottom of the slider
(see image). the controlbar needs and higher z-index that the  images but if I do,

```
#controls{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:2
}
```

The problem is that the browser sets the z-index of the entire body so the control panel is placed above all other items on the page.

can somebody help me fixing this problem?

**image explanation**
gray:border
red:images
black:control bar

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images">
    Images
    <div id="controls">
        Controls
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#images {
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    position: relative; /* This works */
}

#controls {
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute; /* This works */
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5syvbf/

**Explanation:**

The `bottom: 0; left: 0` positions the div 0 pixels from the bottom of the parent-div(`#images`) and 0 pixels from the left side of the parent-div. An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. Here the first parent element is the parent-div has a `position: relative`, ergo it's not static, and the child-div(#controls) will therefore position itself relative to the parent-div, nicely at the bottom.